# SharePoint Retention - Expiration Date not calculating for some items

Tags: sharepoint-server, information-management, retention, information-policy, expiration

I have a retention policy set for a content type. The retention is based on the modified date + 3 years, if the condition is met a custom workflow starts. The recurrence is set to every 7 days. The problem is that i have a number of items in a list, the expiration date for some items is being calculated and for some other it is not being calculated. All items have a content type which this retention policy is enabled.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the issue related to your retention policy or the calculated column?  From your description it sounds as though the expiration date fails to be calculated.  However, all the tags on your question are information management policy related.  How many content types are you using in the list?

Comment: The issue is related to the expiration date column that is calculated automatically when a retention policy is in place. The expiration  date column was not created by myself. I am using around 3-4 content types in the list, these content types are inheriting from the parent content type that has the retention policy enabled.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue is results by large number of items.

The “Information management policy” timer job forces the policy’s formula to evaluate to determine if the items have expired, and the “Expiration policy” timer job kicks off the policy’s expiration action for those items marked as expired by the fist timer job.

Run the “Information management policy” timer job and then "Expiration policy" job manually to see whether the expiration date for some items is being calculated.

Comment: I have already tried to run both jobs manually, i have also increased to logs in some efforts to capture something in the logs but still nothing. The expiration date is not calculated. Expiration date for items with the same content type in the same list are being calculated bu then there are some items that for some reason the field is just not calculated.